# Can not login to docker hub, ubuntu terminal

Tags: docker

I tried to login to docker hub from Ubuntu terminal (credentials are correct for docker hub and I can login to docker from browser)

> > docker login
> >
> > Username: test-my-username-here
> >
> > Password: test-my-password-here
> >
> > Email: test-my-email-here

And it giving below Response which means **Image of Page Not Found**

I also had restarted docker and computer also, still unable to login.
Without login I can't push my image to docker hub

````
Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code [404] : <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>404 : Docker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    * {
        line-height: 1.2;
        margin: 0;
    }

    html {
        color: #71859d;
        display: table;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        background: #fff;
        display: table-cell;
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin: 2em auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    a {
        color: #22b8eb;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


    @media only screen and (max-width: 280px) {
        body,
        p {
            width: 95%;
        }
    }

    #message {
        font-size: 21px;
        text-align: center;
        animation: fadein 2s;
        -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
        /* Firefox */
        -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
        /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-animation: fadein 2s;
        /* Opera */
    }

    @keyframes fadein {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes fadein {
        /* Firefox */
        from {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
        /* Safari and Chrome */
        from {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @-o-keyframes fadein {
        /* Opera */
        from {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="message">
      <img  src=" data:image/png;base64, **Base-64-image-code-here-of-page-not-found** "/>
    </div>
    Try visiting our <a href="http://docker.com" target="_blank">home page</a><br>
    If you think you have arrived here by mistake, please contact us <a href="mailto:support@docker.com">support@docker.com</a>.
</body>

</html>```

[![This image generated as base64 image output in terminal after login][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5bfo.png
````

Comment: What version of docker? The email prompt has been removed for a long while now.

Comment: @BMitch, You r right, I had docker version 1.x and installing docker everytime its on version 1.x only, After following this step [ apt install docker-ce=17.12.0~ce-0~ubuntu ] I got docker version 17.x, and login working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been caused by an outdated docker install. This is apparent from the email prompt that is no longer part of the registry login. Since those older Docker releases, [Docker Hub removed support for an earlier version of the registry protocol](https://www.docker.com/blog/registry-v1-api-deprecation/), which is likely the underlying cause of the issue.